# Fixing osascript clipboard for OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, osascript

In my Ruby application, I've used the following function for a long time to write to the clipboard:

```
def pbcopy(text)
  IO.popen("osascript -e 'set the clipboard to do shell script \"cat\"'","w+") {|pipe| pipe << text}
end
```

I got this code from [here](http://www.coderaptors.com/?action=browse&diff=1&id=Random_tips_for_Mac_OS_X), and it replaced my earlier use of pbpaste through backticks, because it seemed much more reliable with UTF8 and other things. It has always worked perfectly, however with the new OSX Mountain Lion, it stopped working. osascript -e 'set the clipboard to "hi"' works well, so it might be something with the piping that doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked fine with UTF-8 characters:

```
def pbcopy(text)
  IO.popen("pbcopy", "w+") {|pipe| pipe << text}
end

pbcopy "smörgåsbord"
puts `pbpaste`
```

Comment: The characters are still jumbled up when I try to paste the text to a text view on 10.8.

Comment: Not for me, if I paste in TextEdit or the Chrome address field. Perhaps it's different versions of Ruby (1.9.3 for me) or local environment. I'm on 10.8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

`do shell script "cat"` no longer seems to return the STDIN.

You can get the arguments with the `on run` handler though. The `{input, parameters}` form only seems to work in Automator.

```
system("osascript", "-e", "on run {input}
set the clipboard to input
end", "あä")
```

You could also set the [__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING variable](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081231012753422):

```
IO.popen("__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=$UID:0x8000100:0x8000100 pbcopy", "w") { |i|
  i << "あä"
}
```

Comment: The first example you offered does not seem to work - nothing ends up on the clipboard in OSX ML.

Comment: @StianHåklev You're right; `on run {input}` was missing the curly brackets.